# Swift - Display label.text algorithm

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm

I want to compare each word of a fixed sentence with each word from a voice recorded.

I have the following code now :

```
func compareWordwithVoice() {

    let StringToLearn = wordToLearn
    let StringToLearnArr = StringToLearn.components(separatedBy: " ")
    let StringRecordedArr = transcriptionTextField.text.components(separatedBy: " ")

    let wordCount = StringToLearnArr.count
    word?.text = ""
    for count in 0...Int(wordCount)-1{

        if StringRecordedArr.indices.contains(count) {
            if (StringToLearnArr[count] == StringRecordedArr[count]){
                word.textColor = UIColor.green
                word?.text = word.text! + " " + (StringToLearnArr[count])
            } else {
                word.textColor = UIColor.red
                word?.text = word.text! + " " + (StringToLearnArr[count])
            }
        } else {
            word.textColor = UIColor.black
            word?.text = word.text! + " " + (StringToLearnArr[count])
        }
    }
```

wordToLearn represents the sentence to compare with the sentence recorded displayed with transcriptionTextField.text.

The result is displayed with word.text :

- if the two sentences match, the color of word.text is green
- if the two sentences have the same index which means that there is 4 words for each sentence for example but the two sentences don't match, word.text is red
- if the two sentence don't have the same index, word.text is dark

I want to find an algorithm to display each word with his matched color, for example I have to repeat the sentence "Hello my name is Robert" and I record "Hello my friend is Robert", I want to display "Hello my name(name in red) is Robert" and if I record "Hello my name is Robert", I want to display "Hello my name is Robert (all words in green)".

Comment: Sounds pretty straightforward. What part are you having trouble with?

Comment: My algorithm doesn't color each word only color the sentence.

Comment: So why don't you color the word?

Comment: You'll need to look at using `UIAttributesString` to individually color parts of a string. `UILabel.textColor` applies to the whole string.